# campo tipo ReactQuill

Tags: reactjs

tengo un campo tipo ReactQuill que me permite agregar texto con estilos como saltos de líneas y funciona sin problemas, pero ahora necesito agregarle una variable global y que me permita seguir escribiendo, logre montar la variable pero no me deja escribir en el campo.

https://codesandbox.io/s/staging-haze-p6vhf4?file=/src/App.js

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import ReactQuill from "react-quill";
import "react-quill/dist/quill.snow.css";

export default function App() {
  const [descripcion_1, setValue] = useState("");
    
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <ReactQuill
        onChange={setValue}
        theme="snow"
        value={global.info}
      />
      {(global.info = "colombia")}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: quita la linea value={global.info}, porque la colocas ahi? que quieres lograr exactamente?

Comment: necesito que me cargue la variable global en el value y que tambien me permita seguir escribiendo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usa defaultValue en lugar de value:

```
 return (
    <div className="App">
      <ReactQuill
        onChange={setValue}
        theme="snow"
        defaultValue={global.info}
        modules={modules}
        formats={formats}
      />
      {(global.info = "colombia")}
    </div>
  );
```

Esto te permitirá modificar el campo. Las propiedades 'value' y 'defaultValue' son diferentes en el contexto de los campos de componentes `<ReactQuill>` segun la [documentacion](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-quill). Quizá vos que estas mas familiarizado con la librería entiendas esa diferencia.